# React Native - S3 Pre-signed URL upload issues. cURL works, fetch doesn't - 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: javascript, react-native, rest, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

As in the title, I can get a pre-signed URL from lambda with no issue. The URL works in cURL to upload an image without any issue, and also works with a test python script.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this isn't working in javascript (React Native specifically, in Expo).

Here's roughly the code of interest:

```
const getBlob = async (fileUri) => {
    const resp = await fetch(fileUri);
    const imageBody = await resp.blob();
    
    return imageBody;
  };


async function putPhoto(photoURI){
// code to get the S3URL

    const imageBlob = await getBlob(photoURI)

    response = await fetch(S3URL,{
            method: "PUT",    
            body: imageBlob,
            // headers: {
            //     "Content-Type": "application/json"
            // }
         
        })
```

It's especially maddening since the response from S3 includes the URL, which I can explicitly cURL to and successfully resolve:

```
curl -X PUT -T .\test.jpg "https://<bucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com/<lambda generated hash>.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=<>&x-amz-security-token=<>&Expires=<>"
```

With of course 'sensitive data' being replaced in <>.

The only things I can see that others have had common issues with is on the headers - of which I've also tried entering:

```
headers: {}
```

As I would assume that would override any global scope of headers I'm forgetting about.

Any tips? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like S3 is very specific about needing a the right header when getting a fetch() request and doesn't care about those same headers from a cURL. Or at least, needs to be set up as such for fetch in this case.

Python code for lambda:

```
url = boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='put_object', 
        Params={'Bucket': BUCKET_NAME, 'Key': full_id, 'ContentType': 'application/octet-stream'},
        ExpiresIn=3600
    )
```

Critical to add the Content-Type param as shown.

Also, change my code above to (see Content-Type):

```
async function putPhoto(photoURI){
// code to get the S3URL

    const imageBlob = await getBlob(photoURI)

    response = await fetch(S3URL,{
            method: "PUT",    
            body: imageBlob,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
            }
         
        })
```